# hexo blog has a "%20" in the end of URL

Tags: hexo

Here is my blog made with Hexo.

`iwajef.cn`

And when I click on "Home", "About", "Tags" etc., on the header, the URL always ends with a `%20` e.g: `https://iwajef.cn/tags/%20` with a **404 not found page**.

But if I access to `https://iwajef.cn/tags/` normally, it works.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are your redirection URL having a space trailing?

Comment: How do you create a new post, I mean, could you share the command that you write?

Comment: `%20` is a space... Does the url end with one?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dan1st in the question comment area.

I got the same %20 error.

Just simply delete the space between / and || in the theme's _config.yml:

```
home: /|| home
tags: /tags/|| tags
```